# Get value from first span tag in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to know how to get **$39,465,077,974.88** from this beautifulsoup code

```
<td><span>$39,465,077,974.88</span><div><span class="sc-15yy2pl-0 kAXKAX" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:600"><span class="icon-Caret-up"></span>4.59<!-- -->%</span></div></td>
```

I'm new to web scrapers , hopefully you guys have a clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using a [`css selector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471325/4985099),

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one("td > span").text)
```

---

```
$39,465,077,974.88
```

Comment: Thanks. why td > span ???

Comment: Selecting element named <span> that is directly within an element named <td>

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value like this. Since the value you need is inside a `<span>` that is inside a `<td>`

- First select the `<td>` tag using `find()`

  ```
  td = soup.find('td')
  ```
- Next select the `<span>` tag present inside `td`.

  ```
  sp = td.find('span')
  ```
- Print the text of `sp`

  ```
  print(sp.text.strip())
  ```

Here is the complete code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """<td><span>$39,465,077,974.88</span><div><span class="sc-15yy2pl-0 kAXKAX" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:600"><span class="icon-Caret-up"></span>4.59<!-- -->%</span></div></td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
td = soup.find('td')
sp = td.find('span')
print(sp.text.strip())
```

```
$39,465,077,974.88
```